# How to make a pop over view automatically adjust to its content size?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I subclassed a `UIViewController` to present it as a pop over on iPhone using its `popoverPresentationController`.

The view controller's view contains only a `UILabel` that is added using auto layout constraints.

The presented pop over is much larger than the label. I want the pop over to be only as large as necessary to fit its content. I tried by overriding `preferredContentSize` but that didn't work:

```
override var preferredContentSize: CGSize {
    get {
        label.sizeToFit()
        view.sizeToFit()
        return view.bounds.size
    }
    set {}
}
```

How can I make sure the pop over automatically resizes to its content?

Comment: Maybe try setting the text of the label then get its frame after you set the text (might have to call sizeToFit) and then just adjust the size of the view afterwards to whatever you like

Comment: @TNguyen that is just what I did by overriding `preferredContentSize`.

Comment: but where are you changing the text of the label is it in the viewcontroller that's showing this one? Also I don't think you should use `view.sizeToFit()` I think you should manually figure out what size frame you want and set the bounds to be that. Have a look at this `In some cases, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds. ` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622630-sizetofit

Comment: @TNguyen the text is set at view did load, so prior to `preferredContentSize` being called.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code on how you setup the popover. I tried something very simimlar in a sample project it was working for me maybe something else isn't set up properly

Comment: @Manuel were you able to solve the issue in the end?